# Can a regular rasp be used to enlarge a hole in concrete?

Tags: concrete, cinderblock

I need to enlarge a few holes from 40mm to 50mm in a cinder block wall and in a concrete beam.

Chiseling will do much damage and need patching, can I rasp it with a wood rasp?

Comment: Why not just drill a larger hole with a 50mm bit?

Answer (score 5):

The metal on a wood rasp would be way to soft to make any type of dent in the concrete.  The only thing you will do is destroy the rasp.

You should use a roto hammer with the proper sized bit to widen the hole.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can and it **will** work. It will also dull your rasp.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a heavy duty drill and a [diamond encrusted bit](http://www.rotozip.com/en-us/Pages/CategoryDetail.aspx?pid=5040_5039#), such as this one

[image: diamond bit]

They can be found on-line and in some big box stores for about $20.

When grinding or cutting very hard materials like concrete, you should use a lubricant to reduce heat.  Usually a small constant drip of water at the cut point helps.

```
 Images and links for illustration only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct tool for rasping concrete but it won't fit in a 2" hole. I suppose you could ruin a file (and the better part of a day) to get it done; CMU's aren't *that* hard.

[image]

<sub>[source](http://www.demandproducts.com/EIFS-items/item.php?l2=3,3,45&sku=CSK5)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my own answer since I tried to use the rasp.

It didn't work. The rasp can ease hard corners on cinder block and even a little bit on concrete, but it won't bite enough to enlarge a hole.

The method I use was a hammer drill with a chisel bit. I hold the chisel against where I want the edge to be and pressed the trigger very slowly. I did this so that it dig about 1 cm inside the concrete, then I move to the side and did that again making a contour. After that I used more force to break inside the contour. That way I could make a pretty good edge that requires minimum patching.